# Modify function based on whether URI contains key or no key

Tags: python, airflow

Have to modify the function below so that if there is a key in the URI it downloads the key but if there is no key in the URI then it does not do anything. Format of the 2 URIs will be either #1 or #2 where #1 uses a key and #2 does not

#1 `ssh://user@host.com?key_file=%2Ftmp%2-user-ssh-key` (uri with key)

#2 `sftp://user:password@host.com:22` (uri without key)

--original function

```
def retrieve_ssh_key_var(self):
    key_file = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id=self.sftp_conn_id).key_file
    return basename(key_file)
```

--I have tried this but so far not working.

```
def retrieve_ssh_key_var(self):
    if 'key_file' in self.sftp_conn_id
        try:
            key_file = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id=self.sftp_conn_id).key_file
            return basename(key_file)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: "do nothing" needs to be in the caller code. It has to check the return value of the function and skip the download if it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use [urllib.parse.parseqs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to parse out the url's query parameters before proceeding with your logic.